# DataReader is still open due to my Query

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datareader

I have this error about the DataReader still open but I found out if I use a different query/command it works fine

[image]

so the problem is my mycommand string, but this is what I need to load the needed data, so any advice how to fix it? Thanks

```
     Private Sub daily()
    Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor()
        MySQLcon.ConnectionString = MySQLserver
        MySQLcon.Open()
        'strPath & "\" & txtName.Text & ".xlsx"
        Dim dte As String = cboDate1.Text
        Dim myCommand1 As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand
        Dim myadapter As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter
        Dim mybuilder As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommandBuilder
        Dim mydatatable As New DataTable
        Dim mydataset As New DataSet
        myCommand1.Connection = MySQLcon

        'myCommand1.CommandText = "SELECT  `" + dte + "`.`Users`,concat((`users`.`Last Name`),', ',(`users`.`First Name`)) as `Name`,'" + dte + "'  as Date,`" + dte + "`.`Activity`,`" + dte + "`.`Field1` as `Project Name`,`" + dte + "`.`Field2` as `Job Name` ," + _
        '    "SUM(`" + dte + "`.`Field4`) as `Records`, SUM(`" + dte + "`.`Field5`)as Pages," + _
        '    "ROUND(sum(TIME_TO_SEC(`" + dte + "`.`Elapsed Time`))/3600,2)as `Hours`," + _
        '    "'G' as `REGS/HR`," + _
        '    "'H' as `PGS/HR`" + _
        '    "FROM `" + dte + "`" + _
        '    "INNER JOIN `users`" + _
        '    "ON `" + dte + "`.`Users`=`users`.`Employee ID`" + _
        '    "Where `" + dte + "`.`Group` = 'DATA ENTRY' and `" + dte + "`.`Field1` <> 'OVER-BREAK 1' and `" + dte + "`.`Field1` <> 'OVER-BREAK 2'  and (`" + dte + "`.`Activity` = 'KE' or `" + dte + "`.`Activity` = 'CH' or `" + dte + "`.`Activity` = 'SJ' or `" + dte + "`.`Activity` = 'VE' or `" + dte + "`.`Activity` = 'MB' or `" + dte + "`.`Activity` = 'TD' or `" + dte + "`.`Activity` = 'LK'  or `" + dte + "`.`Activity` = 'PG')" + _
        '    "GROUP BY  `" + dte + "`.`Users`, `" + dte + "`.`Activity`, `" + dte + "`.`Field1`"

        myCommand1.CommandText = "SELECT  `MERGED DATAENTRY`.`Users`,concat((`users`.`Last Name`),', ',(`users`.`First Name`)) as `Name`,'" + cboDate1.Text & " - " & cboDate2.Text + "'  as Date,`MERGED DATAENTRY`.`Activity`,`MERGED DATAENTRY`.`Field1` as `Project Name`,`MERGED DATAENTRY`.`Field2` as `Job Name` ," + _
            "SUM(`MERGED DATAENTRY`.`Field4`) as `Records`, SUM(`MERGED DATAENTRY`.`Field5`)as Pages," + _
            "ROUND(sum(TIME_TO_SEC(`MERGED DATAENTRY`.`Elapsed Time`))/3600,2)as `Hours`," + _
            "'G' as `REGS/HR`," + _
            "'H' as `PGS/HR`" + _
            "FROM `MERGED DATAENTRY`" + _
            "INNER JOIN `users`" + _
            "ON `MERGED DATAENTRY`.`Users`=`users`.`Employee ID`" + _
            "Where `MERGED DATAENTRY`.`Group` = 'DATA ENTRY' and `MERGED DATAENTRY`.`Field1` <> 'OVER-BREAK 1' and `MERGED DATAENTRY`.`Field1` <> 'OVER-BREAK 2'  and (`MERGED DATAENTRY`.`Activity` = 'KE' or `MERGED DATAENTRY`.`Activity` = 'CH' or `MERGED DATAENTRY`.`Activity` = 'SJ' or `MERGED DATAENTRY`.`Activity` = 'VE' or `MERGED DATAENTRY`.`Activity` = 'MB' or `MERGED DATAENTRY`.`Activity` = 'TD' or `MERGED DATAENTRY`.`Activity` = 'LK'  or `MERGED DATAENTRY`.`Activity` = 'PG')" + _
            "GROUP BY  `MERGED DATAENTRY`.`Users`, `MERGED DATAENTRY`.`Activity`, `MERGED DATAENTRY`.`Field1`"
        myadapter.SelectCommand = myCommand1
        myadapter.Fill(mydataset)
        mydataset.Tables.Add(mydatatable)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = mydataset.Tables(0)

        Dim xlApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
        Dim xlWorkBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
        Dim xlWorkSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
        Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value


        Dim i As Integer
        Dim j As Integer

        xlApp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue)
        xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("sheet1")


        For i = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
            For j = 0 To DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1
                For k As Integer = 1 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count
                    'Dim style As Excel.Style = xlWorkSheet.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Styles.Add("NewStyle")
                    'style.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow)
                    'xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, k).Style = "NewStyle"
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, k) = DataGridView1.Columns(k - 1).HeaderText
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells(i + 2, j + 1) = DataGridView1(j, i).Value.ToString()
                    If DataGridView1(j, i).ColumnIndex = 9 Then
                        xlWorkSheet.Cells(i + 2, j + 1) = "=ROUND(" & DataGridView1(j, i).Value.ToString() & (DataGridView1(j, i).RowIndex + 2) & "/" & "I" & (DataGridView1(j, i).RowIndex + 2) & ",2)"

                    End If
                    If DataGridView1(j, i).ColumnIndex = 10 Then
                        xlWorkSheet.Cells(i + 2, j + 1) = "=ROUND(" & DataGridView1(j, i).Value.ToString() & (DataGridView1(j, i).RowIndex + 2) & "/" & "I" & (DataGridView1(j, i).RowIndex + 2) & ",2)"

                    End If
                Next
            Next
        Next

        xlWorkSheet.SaveAs(strPath & "\" & txtName.Text & ".xlsx")
        xlWorkBook.Close()
        xlApp.Quit()
        ReleaseObject(xlApp)
        ReleaseObject(xlWorkBook)
        ReleaseObject(xlWorkSheet)
        MessageBox.Show("File Export Successfully!")
  MySQLcon.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: Please show all the code in the sub that contains this error. Images are not really useful in this context.

Answer (score 2):

MySqlDataAdapter is IDisposable and you are not disposing it
MySQLcon and MySQLserver are defined outside the code you posted, so I am making some assumptions here.

I would imagine there is connection pooling going on here, ie you do not *really* get a new db connection each time you run this.  As you are not disposing of your MySqlDataAdapter etc when you hit this code for the 2nd or subsequent time you still have on open 'query' with the DB.

You need to check for IDisposable on all of:

```
Dim myCommand1 As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand
Dim myadapter As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter
Dim mybuilder As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommandBuilder
.....
```

And change to Using statments, ie:

```
Using myadapter As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter
    Using myCommand1 As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand
        Using mybuilder As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommandBuilder
        .....
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```

Though i suspect the DataAdaptor is the only one that really matters.

Try to read up on IDisposable

NB  mydataset.Tables.Add(mydatatable) looks pointless, you are adding a blank table to an already filled dataset

Comment: I add Try-Catch and got this error **Not allowed to change the 'ConnectionString' property while the connection(state-Open)**

Comment: i found out the this is my problem **myCommand1.Connection = MySQLcon**